# Java Application for comercial use

Tags: java

I wrote an application in Java. I have a JavaSE-1.8 (jre) execution environment in my project. Do I need any license to distribute the application for commercial purposes? Or does the client need any license?

Comment: _Exactly_ which JRE are you distributing, and what license is it under? "JavaSE-1.8 (jre)" is not precise enough as licensing conditions vary between vendors.

Comment: org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_15.0.2.v20210201-0955

Comment: And what license is that under?

Comment: If this is [the same OpenJDK I am aware of](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk), then we are dealing with GPLv2, and with Eclipse.org involved you will probably see a lot of EPL code. But look at the folder 'jdk-19+36\legal\java.base\' in the repository, which shows a hole list of different licenses for different components.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.